# Saving my BlobField in a different codepage

Tags: delphi-2010, firebird2.5

My simple code is:

```pascal
var
  TMPStream : TStringStream;
  myencoding: TEncoding;

...

try 
  myencoding := TEncoding.GetEncoding(CP_UTF8);
  TMPStream := TStringStream.Create('', myencoding);

  try
    (IBQueryTMP.FieldByName('MYTEXT') as TBlobField).SaveToStream(TMPStream);
    TMPStream.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'myfile.txt');
  except
    Showmessage ('Error');
  end;
finally    
  TMPStream.Free;
  myencoding.Free;
end;
```

As I see in the file (for instance, in Notepad++), the codepage is UTF-16 Little Endian, although it was declared UTF-8. The database is UTF-8, too.

What's wrong?

Comment: You really should be using `TEncoding.UTF8` instead of `TEncoding.GetEncoding(CP_UTF8)`. However, it doesn't matter, because you are not actually using the `TEncoding` for anything useful. You are saving arbitrary bytes as-is from the Blob into the stream, and then saving the stream as-is to file. The bytes are not interpreted in any way during that process. So, what is stored in the DB is what ends up in your file. Based on that, the text in the blob must be UTF-16 to begin with, not UTF-8. If you want to re-encode that UTF-16 to UTF-8 in your file, this is the wrong approach for doing that.

Comment: Try this instead: `TFile.WriteAllText(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'myfile.txt', IBQueryTMP.FieldByName('MYTEXT').AsString, TEncoding.UTF8);`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thx! It works!Honestly, I thought streaming (SaveToStream) was converting text at runtime and your explanation (text with UTF-16 code page in Blob) speaks for itself

Comment: `TStringStream` is a wrapper for reading/writing a `String` in memory. Its assigned `TEncoding` only gets used when converting bytes to `String`, or vice versa. But your original code wasn't doing that. It was treating the stream more like a `TMemoryStream` instead. Which you could have used instead, and the code would have behaved in exactly the same way.